# Is there a way to work with 2 separate workbooks in a single excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 separate workbooks which data on one is side infos about the main items on the other,
Each sheet on any of them has a sheet on the other .
I have VBA code that uses the infos on the 1st workbook to create sheets based on values in sheets.
The second workbook should keep track of the item histories , I can't add data to main item sheet because I have counters in VBA using rows number. Beside if I add second sheet next to main sheet number of sheets doubles and file grows too much.
Is there a way that I could have these two workbook integrated in a file so I can write VBA code for them and they are just in one place? I can use 2 separate files instead of merging two workbooks, but there is a risk that if user wants to transfer the data just copy the main file and misses the history file or the history file accidentally be deleted.
Maybe I am too sensitive on this, But either way possible or not , knowing is good though.
Also any recommendation with VBA is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One Workbook = one Excel document". Fullstop - that's by design.

One VBA program can access multiple workbooks at once, there is no need to store the program in the same workbook where the processed data is placed. You just have write the program in a way where you use explicit workbook and sheet variables when accessing ranges and cells, not relying on the "active sheet" or "active workbook".

Educating your users not to delete a "history file" is a different problem which should not be intermixed with your question. If you still want all in one file, you can duplicate all sheets (for example, by adding a suffix "_H" for the historical data) and integrate all sheets into one document (check for the 30 characters limit on sheet names). But the file size will be then always (roughly) the sum of the size of the two original files - regardless how you combine the different documents - the same would obviously be the result if there would be an option to combine two workbooks into one file.